# DB2: Construct Variable inside stored procedure with current date?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a stored procedure that basically updates the LASTUPDATE times of some rows and I want to have a variable inside the stored procedure that is basically: `Date + " " + "20:30:00"` So when the stored procedure is run it looks something like this:

```
update 
    person 
set 
    LASTUPDATETIME='2012-06-18 20:30:00', 
    NAME='Mike', 
where (
    SOME_PK='123'
);
```

but if I was to run the stored procedure tomorrow it would look like so:

```
update 
    person 
set 
    LASTUPDATETIME='2012-06-19 20:30:00', 
    NAME='Mike', 
where (
    SOME_PK='123'
);
```

P.S The time never changes, it should always be 20:30:00 no matter when the procedure is called, I’m just interested in the date with the format Year-Month-day.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`VARCHAR_FORMAT()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html) function to get the current date as a string, and then append your hard coded time to it:

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 20:30:00'
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

If you want to store the result as a `TIMESTAMP` data type, you can use the [`TIMESTAMP`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000859.html) function:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE, '20:30:00')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Tested on DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, and z/OS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried it and it works.

Just to confirm on how I would store it and use it as a variable, would the following work:

``DECLARE date_time varchar(4000);
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 20:30:00' INTO date_time
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

update 
    person 
set 
    LASTUPDATETIME=date_time, 
    NAME='Mike', 
where (
    SOME_PK='123'
);

update 
    person 
set 
    LASTUPDATETIME=date_time, 
    NAME='Mo', 
where (
    SOME_PK='124'
);``

Comment: I believe so, yes.  Although, I would personally convert it back to and store it as a `TIMESTAMP` type, it would make date-related operations so much easier.  However, you might not be able to do that if you're working with a legacy schema.

Comment: Given that `TIMESTAMP()` has a two-parameter version (one for date, the other for time, or their string representations), the call to `VARCHAR_FORMAT()` probably isn't necessary.

Comment: @X-Zero: Hey, you're right! I updated the answer.  I think the `VARCHAR_FORMAT` is still necessary for the string version, though.

Comment: Probably, but I'd actually _start_ with it as a timestamp, and wrap _that_ in any formatting conversion - especially as that would allow you to be more 'flexible' (although storage should, of course, be in the actual type).